# WSO2 BAM Amazon Image Availability

Tags: amazon-ec2, wso2, wso2-bam

Is there any public Amazon AMI available for WSO2 BAM or CEP products ?
I have tried looking into AWS marketplace but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, i think. But you can create for yourself using the binaries distributed.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to create my own private AMI's

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not in the AWS Marketplace. However there are some WSO2 Community AMIs in regions "Asia Pacific (Singapore)" and "US East - 1 (N. Virginia)". As far as I know, there are no AMI's for particular WSO2 products, but there is an AMI for WSO2 Stratos, the cloud enabled WSO2 platform, which indeed includes BAM, CEP, and all the other products, pre-configured and ready for multi-tenancy, scaling, and so on.

http://wso2.com/cloud/stratos/

http://docs.wso2.org/display/Stratos200/Quick+Start+Guide